# Einops rearrange function basic functionallity

Tags: torch, einops

I'm trying to grok the einops syntax for tensor reordering, but am somehow missing the point

If I have the following matrix:

```
mat = torch.randint(1, 10, (8,4))
```

I understand what the following command does:

```
rearrange(mat, '(h n) w -> (n h) w', n = 2)
```

But can't really wrap my head around the following ones:

```
rearrange(mat, '(n h) w -> (h n) w', n = 2)
```

```
rearrange(mat, '(n h) w -> (h n) w', n = 4)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rearrange(mat, '(h n) w -> (n h) w', n = 2)
and
rearrange(mat, '(n h) w -> (h n) w', n = 2)
```

are inversions of each other. If you can imagine what one does, second makes reverse transform

As for the latter, mat is 8x4

```
rearrange(mat, '(n h) w -> (h n) w', n = 4)
```

So you first split first dimension in 4x2 (below I ignore w dimension, because nothing special happens with it)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

to

```
[0, 1, 
 2, 3, 
 4, 5, 
 6, 7]
```

then you change order of axes to 2x4 (transpose)

```
[0, 2, 4, 6,
 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

then merge two dimensions into one

```
[0, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

If you still don't feel how that works, take simpler examples like

```
rearrange(np.arange(50), '(h n) -> h n', h=5)
rearrange(np.arange(50), '(h n) -> h n', h=10)
rearrange(np.arange(50), '(h n) -> n h', h=10)
```

etc. So that you could track movement of each element in the matrix